# Excel Data Validation not processing recent cell-data from smartphone input

Tags: excel

- I have recently observed an issue regarding my data in a column that I use to perform data validation on my spreadsheet.
- So There is nothing wrong with  the formula, neither is there anything from with the use of data validation.
- It should be looking for duplicate entries, which works quite fine.
- The issue is that it no longer recognizes input made from a smartphone using the excel app.
- so what i did was to retype cell text field from my PC and it worked perfectly.

Is there a way that I can continue using this technique (Data validation) without having to re-enter data from a PC in order for it to process?

Comment: Can you add more detail to your question? What's the formula you're using, for example? What data validation? This will help us have a [reprex]...

Answer (score 0):

### Certainly!   Yes, that is possible.

---

> *But... with all the possibilities in today's world, is your current strategy the one that is the best for you?*

- *That is something I **cannot** answer for you.*
- *That is something I **cannot** enumerate for you.*

> *But... There is something that I can introduce to you.*

---

### PowerQuery

PowerQuery was a free add-on for Excel 2010 and 2013 and it has been baked directly into Excel for more than half a decade.  So, if you're using the mobile app then you probably have a modern version of Excel with PowerQuery right at your finger tips.

Your first step if to determine how you want to make your data available for Excel to get.  Go to the Data Tab on the ribbon and review your options in the "Get Extetnal Data" group.

It doesn't matter if free data is your Creed and your most intimate moments are publicly available through your raw data feed.  Or if paranoia is the reason why you constantly drive around the block scraping SSIDs before squirreling them away to SQL server for detailed analysis. Or if you're using a USB cable to transfer photos to your PC because your mom walked in on you without knocking and was so disgusted by what she saw on your desktop that you're banned from the family LAN... For life.  None of that matters because Excel can connect to your data in so many ways that one of them will be perfect for you.

There is a sense of familiarity when Importing your data into PowerQuery.  It's not unlike following those timeless MS Wizards; but nothing like the uncanny sensation of being dropped into the PowerQuery editor.  It is simultaneously the same as Excel and different from Excel and it may be the closest you ever come to visiting a parallel universe.  Many of the same tools are available but they behave just slightly differently.  And in some cases, like the Text To Columns tool, it is light years ahead of Excel and you will find yourself cursing at MS for not using it as a replacement for the old tool.

When you're done transforming your data, you'll have a tight clean table. But the real prize, is that you have  fully automated pipe from source to product .

Answer (score 0):

I figured that the phone user included extra spaces when inputting the data.

- So i Used the TRIM() function which takes care of the extra spaces between, before, or after each word, and that did the job.
- Therefore the major error was that there were additional spaces that was not recognized in the tested data.